# Deleting windows partitions: which one I can safely remove?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

[image: Partition pic]

I currently have my disk partitioned as shown in the picture. I want to remove all windows related partition (and tidy up the partition table a bit in the process, removing weird 1mb partitions if possible). If it is relevant, I will then want to move my /home folder the newly freed space ( I know about the guid here)

I have a few ones which I am unsure about, can you please tell me wheter they are ok to remove?

Also, if all my relevant data is on the sda6 partition (which I will not touch), can I safely remove the others without fear of losing the data in it?

Partitions I am unsure about:

- sda2, I think this is the GRUB partition, so I should not remove it, correct? -> Yes, NOT SAFE TO REMOVE
- sda3,5,9 , I have no idea what these are - > All safe to remove

What I think is safe to remove:

- sda4, my windows partition
- sda1,sda7,sda8

What I don't want remove:

- sda10 and sda11, my ubuntu partition
- sda6, this is just a storage partition on the disk

Comment: Usefull link https://askubuntu.com/questions/635487/is-it-safe-to-remove-diag-flagged-partitions/635575#635575

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely don't want to mess with /dev/sda2. That is used for booting up your system. It's how your EFI firmware knows where to hand off the boot process to the kernel.

As for /dev/sda3 and ~/sda9, those both look like they've either been partitioned in something that Ubuntu can't see (HIGHLY UNLIKELY), or they haven't been partitioned at all. They should be safe to add to the partitions that you want to create/extend.

I'm not sure what's in /dev/sda5, so I'm not sure what to tell you there. From it's size, it looks like it should be the Windows recovery console, but /dev/sda1 is already labelled as RE tools. I would look at mounting the partition, viewing what's on it, and maybe do some web searching based on what you find to figure out if it's safe to remove or not. It's probably Windows related, and safe to remove, since Ubuntu generally doesn't use NTFS unless you specify, but I would still proceed with caution.

Comment: sda5 looks like has only a System\ Volume\ Information/tracking.log which I can open with vi and only presents me funny symbols, which uses all 26mb that are used on the partition

Comment: Looking up on google, the tracking.log is a windows restore related partition. I am going to assume is safe to delete and remove it. Thanks